# git-svn : prevent commit if svn rebase is needed

Tags: git, git-svn

Two people are running git locally and using git-svn to sync with a remote master SVN server.

Person A does an SVN REBASE and modifies their local git file.
Person B also does a SVN REBASE and modifies the same file locally in their git for a different issue.

Person B commits using GIT SVN DCOMMIT.

Person A commits using GIT SVN DCOMMIT but since they are missing the Person B commit, the Person B's commit is rolled back.

Is there any way to flag GIT SVN DCOMMIT if the remote SVN server needs to be rebased?

Answer (score -1):

Your usage above either has an error or is very strange.  what should happen:

---

1) both check out the repository via `git svn clone`

2) When A or B makes changes, they should:

2a) make the change

2b) `git commit` it

2c) either continue working (going to 2a) or push the change upward

3) before commiting their own stuff, they'll need to do a `git svn rebase`.  git-svn will actually already prevent you from going to step 4 until you're in sync with the upstream svn repo

4) `git svn dcommit`

---

If you follow the above steps, you shouldn't be able to go from step #3 to a successful step 4 (`git dcommit`) without first running rebase.  Since rebase moves all your changes to the top of the SVN tree within git, you will never reverse someone else's changes.

Now....  If you're trying to do `git pull`s from A to B or B to A: there be dragons; you shouldn't do that.  (well, you can, but it's much more tricky; the above is much safer)

Comment: if the above is true, is it possible the svn dcommit merge is what "rolled back" the first persons commit?

Comment: Actually is not what we see. If you do a dcommit, it is commited to svn and then the git repository pulls down any commits from svn and applies them.

Comment: afaik you can't "commit with svn rebase" rebase (both git's and git svn's) work with existing commits, to create new ones you use `commit` on git and `dcommit` for copying those to svn.

Comment: also, as Wes said git shouldn't let you dcommit unless you have the latest svn revision locally but I admit I haven't experienced that particular case so I can't assure you it doesn't.

Comment: I fixed the text as you are 100% right I used the wrong commands for the commit step. We do not see dcommit stopping if you don't have the latest svn revision. Instead after the dcommit a svn rebase is done.